# nivo slider left arrow picture bugged

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I have implemented the nivo slider (with default theme) successfully except for one issue.

The left arrow on the slider is showing a small part of the right arrow. The right arrow on the other hand is being displayed correctly.

How come the left side of the sprite is not rendered properly but the right one is?

[Arrow picture](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/2936/arrowht.png)

The only place where the arrow.png picture is declared is in the next css section:

```
.theme-default .nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(../Images/slider/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look right below that class in the `nivo-slider` css you will notice some classes called `a.nivo-nextNav` and `a.nivo-prevNav` which are applying a background position.

The `left` property on `a.nivo-prevNav` must be wrong for the distribution of the plugin you have. If you adjust that to say `11px` (you will have to play with it, to get it just right) it will fix your problem.

Comment: The problem was in ".theme-default .nivo-directionNav a " oddly enough. When changing the width from 30px to 24px it solved the arrow issue.

Comment: @Complexity to save on plugin space they use the same image for both the right and left nav, then they just adjust the position of the image. It works, but it can be confusing at times.

Comment: @Complexity so by changing the width, you made the 'viewing-window', so to speak, smaller, which made the right arrow disappear, however you have to be careful with that because it makes the clickable area of the button smaller. If you have the time I would play with the background position so that your clickable area stays the same.